# Is there a Lorentz invariant approximation to General Relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, approximations, linearized-theory

Since General Relativity is the most accurate description of gravity is there any possible way to derive a Lorentz invariant theory from: $$R_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2} g_{\mu\nu}R+\Lambda g_{\mu\nu}=kT_{\mu\nu}$$

Assuming the metric is in the form: $g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}$ where $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ is the flat space time metric and $h_{\mu\nu}$ is a disturbance in the metric.

If there is a derivation for a Lorentz invariant theory, what would each component of the metric correspond to?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like that you're looking for [weak field approximations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearized_gravity).

Comment: @Qmechanic I'm asking for a more specific case, not asking about GEM or the Newtonian case. I'm asking is there a Lorentz invariant theory that can be derived as an approximation to General Relativity. I'm also asking what does the components of the metric correspond to in the force field components

Comment: It seems to me like the weak field approximations or linearized gravity are the answer your question.  If that is not what you are looking for, please edit your question, so that it clear asks what you mean.  How is your case different?

Comment: @PaulT. I'm asking for a Lorentz invariant weak field approximation. It's not different, but a more specific case of the weak field approximations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we take a flat background and perturb around it, $g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu} + h_{\mu\nu}$, the Riemann tensor takes the form,

$$R_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta} = \frac12 (h_{\alpha\delta,\beta\gamma}+ h_{\beta\gamma,\alpha\beta} - h_{\alpha\gamma,\beta\delta}-h_{\beta\delta,\alpha\gamma}),$$

where commas denote covariant derivatives, which are reduced to partial derivatives, since they are taken with respect to the background in perturbation theory, and in this case it is just $\eta_{\mu\nu}$.

Noting that $g^{\mu\nu}=\eta^{\mu\nu}-h^{\mu\nu}$ (a good exercise to show this using the properties you know about a metric), the Einstein field equations read,

$$\partial^\alpha\partial_\nu {h}_{\mu\alpha} + \partial_\mu \partial^\alpha h_{\nu\alpha} - \partial^\alpha\partial_\alpha h_{\mu\nu} - \partial_\mu\partial_\nu h^{\alpha\beta}h_{\alpha\beta}-\eta_{\mu\nu}(\partial^\alpha\partial^\beta h_{\alpha\beta} - \partial^\alpha\partial_\alpha h^{\gamma\delta}h_{\gamma\delta}) = 16\pi T_{\mu\nu}.$$

We have yet to choose a gauge, and the choice often depends on the problem at hand. It can at times reduce it to simply the wave equation, which one can solve with Green's functions.

Knowing the form of the curvature tensor, you can compute the action $S \sim \int \mathrm{d}^dx \sqrt{|g|}R$ and find a Lorentz invariant theory, which can in fact be quantised as well, like with other field theories, though it leads to a non-renormalisable field theory.

Comment: Is there a known example of a Lorentz invariant approximation of gravity, and if so what equations do they form?

Comment: @huhuu this is an approximation of gravity. You're approximating it to first order in perturbation theory.

Comment: Will a higher order result in a Lorentz invariant theory

Comment: @huhuu It is Lorentz invariant already at first order.

Comment: So if we solve for $h_{\mu\nu}$ and solve the geodesic equation we can get a Lorentz invariant vector field theory.